# CSS Transition is not being applied

Tags: css

I have created a simple check-box switch, here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aseVX as you have noticed, when you click the little circle jumps, i am trying to make it smoothly shift from left to right and right to left. I tried adding CSS transition and that didn't make it work. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

```
/*Checkbox Switch*/
 .switch p, .switch label {
    display: inline;
}
.switch label {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.switch label > span {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    -ms-transition: all .15s linear;
    -o-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: all .15s linear;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
    background-color: #316C94;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.switch span span {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #A6A6A6;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .15s ease;
    -o-transition: all .15s ease;
    transition: all .15s ease;
}
.switch label > span:hover span {
    width: 30px;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span span {
    right: 2px;
    left: auto;
    border: none;
}
/*Checkbox Switch > Disabled*/
 .switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;
    border: 1px solid #A6A6A6 !important;
}
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span span, .switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span span:hover {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border: 1px solid #A6A6A6 !important;
    width: 24px !important;
}
```

Comment: You can't transition from a numerical value to a keyword as you are with `left: auto;`

Comment: What would you recommend me to do?

Comment: That would depend. Is the `span`'s width static?

Comment: Yes, I just want to move it to the right when its checked and to the left when it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Adrift said in the comments, you cannot animate to a state of `auto`

But, since you said the width is set, you can animate to the left value that fits the width like so

```
.switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span span {
    left: 23px;
    border: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/aseVX/3/)

In addition I added a change the `left` position when the checkbox was checked and it was hovered

The prefixed versions of `border-radius` are not needed because `-moz-border-radius` was never a thing and browsers that don't support `border-radius` will not support transitions or anything like that either

Also, the `!important`s are not needed, if the selector is has a higher precedence or the same precedence but is further down the stylesheet, the styles will automatically be overridden. This is because CSS is a *cascading* language, meaning styles will apply over previous ones if they can. `!important` should try to be avoided as it causes issues when projects get large and such

Comment: Thank you! that solved it, however are you sure about the -moz-border-radius?

Comment: So I only need to use border-radius? remove -webkit-border-radius and -moz-border-radius ?